# MySQL Server performance

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a few questions regarding MySQL server running under Windows Server 2008 R2.

1) How do I check the number of allowed connections?

2) How do I turn on query logging to see performance of queries executed?

3) As I understand MySQL is multithreaded, will increasing the number of allowed connections increase performance on a Quad Core system?

4) Will having a cluster setup increase performance?

5) How can I setup load shedding with multiple MySQL servers in a cluster?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I moved the question and I got a brilliant answer on that side.

The answer can be viewed at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17511/mysql-server-performance/17540#17540

Thanks